# What did the Dwarves do during the first reign of Sauron, and why weren't they at The War of the Last Alliance?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

As the question states we hear that Sauron fell during The War of the Last Alliance where Men and Elves united to take down Sauron and his forces.

But what about the Dwarves of Middle-earth? What did they do during the time that lead up to the war of the Last Alliance (from the forging of the Ring of Power to Sauron's fall at the war of the last alliance)?

Were they themselves besieged by Sauron's forces and as such unable to spare any troops to help in that battle? Did they remain neutral? Maybe the majority actually joined Sauron? What was the reason as to why they aren't recorded as having sent forces (or at least so few that it wasn't recorded anywhere) to battle Sauron along with the Men and Elves during The War of the Last Alliance?

Comment: Gonna take a wild guess at "continued mining".

Comment: Part 1 - Durin IV led a force from Moria to fight on the side of the Elves/Men, but otherwise the Dwarves didn't seem to participate significantly in the war. I'd suggest that the rings Sauron gave them focused their attention on mining/wealth accumulation as they were known to have made the Dwarf kings greedy, and no doubt made them (even more) insular and distrusting as well. Thus their interest in allying with each other, or Elves/Men, and putting themselves at risk for the selfsame, seems unlikely ...

Comment: Part 2 -  ... not to mention that as far as I can tell, only the Dwarves of Moria were meaningfully harmed by Sauron/Annatar devastating Eregion since they had a lot of traffic with Celebrimbor/Eregion. If you put those two together (the rings corrupting them to a degree, plus their lack of direct interest in the precipitating events (Eregion and Numenor)), plus the Dwarves inherent nature of isolationism, it isn't a stretch that they wouldn't participate in the war.

Comment: They were delving too deeply.

Answer (score 32):

In general, the Dwarves seem to have followed an isolationist strategy during the Second Age. They closed the gates of Moria and secured themselves; the appendices to Lord of the Rings have this to say:

> The power of Moria endured throughout the Dark Years and the dominion of Sauron, for though Eregion was destroyed and the gates of Moria were shut, the halls of Khazad-dum were too deep and strong and filled with a people too numerous and valiant for Sauron to conquer from without. Thus its wealth remained long unravished, though its people began to dwindle.

The Tale of Years in the appendices specifies that the gates of Moria were closed in 1697 of the Second Age, the year when Eregion was laid waste, Celebrimbor killed, and Rivendell founded.

The Silmarillion tells how during the Last Alliance every living thing in Middle Earth (even the birds and beasts) was divided, and some of each could be found in both hosts (except for the Elves, who all followed Gil-galad). Thus there were some Dwarves fighting both for and against Sauron; but specifically

> Of the Dwarves few fought upon either side; but the kindred of Durin of Moria fought against Sauron.

Comment: It wouldn’t surprise me if the Dwarves that did fight for Sauron were Dwarven equivalents of Easterlings, off in lands Sauron always had more control over and we hear very little about.

Comment: "The Silmarillion tells how during the Last Alliance every living thing in Middle Earth (even the birds and beasts) was divided, and some of each could be found in both hosts (except for the Elves, who all followed Gil-galad)." Wait, are you saying that there were orcs that fought against Sauron?

Comment: @nick012000: Good point! Perhaps an oversight?

Comment: I've never really taken that line literally. As a poetic exaggeration, I take it to mean there were Men and Dwarves on both sides, both sides used pack animals, Eagles on one side and crows on the other, etc. If any Orcs fought *against* the Orcs in Sauron's armies, it was likely as an independent orc-on-orc conflict, rather than actually being allied with Elves and Men.

Comment: "save the Elves only" - the fact that he included a single explicit exception at least casts a skeptical gaze on the "poetic exaggeration" hypothesis.

Comment: In-universe, that's likely a phrase written by an Elf. "Only we Elves were united against Sauron." is the implication. Or do you think that both sides literally had, say, combat voles sneaking behind enemy lines to wreak havoc on sacks of grain?

Comment: @chepner LotR/Redwall crossover when?

Answer (score 9):

> All living things were divided in that day, and some of every kind, even of beasts and birds, were found in either host, save the Elves only. They alone were undivided and followed Gil-galad. **Of the Dwarves few fought upon either side; but the kindred of Durin of Moria fought against Sauron.**
>
> The Silmarillion, of the Rings of power and the Third Age

Answer (score 1):

The Dwarves were strongly allied with Men during the beginning of the second age, but it fell apart after Eregion was destroyed, and after that the Dwarves kept to themselves.

> The Second Age had reached only the middle of its course (c. Second Age 1695) when **[Sauron] invaded Eriador and destroyed Eregion, a small realm established by the Eldar migrating from the ruin of Beleriand that had formed an alliance also with the Longbeards of Moria. This marked the end of the Alliance of the Longbeards with Men of the North.** For though Moria remained impregnable for many centuries, the Orks reinforced and commanded by servants of Sauron invaded the mountains again. Gundabad was re-taken, the Ered Mithrin infested and the communication between Moria and the Iron Hills for a time cut off. The Men of the Alliance were involved in war not only with Orks but with alien Men of evil sort. For Sauron had acquired dominion over many savage tribes in the East (of old corrupted by Morgoth), and he now urged them to seek land and booty in the West. When the storm passed, the Men of the old Alliance were diminished and scattered, and those that lingered on in their old regions were impoverished, and lived mostly in caves or in the borders of the Forest.
> <sub>*The Peoples of Middle-earth* "Of Dwarves and Men"</sub>